# Rangy - Closing Parent Element before insertElement

Tags: dom, rangy

I have a text like

```
<AnyTag>here is a sample test text and more text</AnyTag>.
```

Now I am selecting "test" and clicking an italic button in my page and it creates a new element `<span class="ItalicClass">` and it `surroundContents()`. This woks fine.

Now I have text like

```
<AnyTag>here is a <i>sample test text</i> and more text</AnyTag>.
```

Now if I select "test" it does the same but I would like to close the parent first and then insert the new element. I know the `parentNode` hence I can insert a new class in the `span` element. Same way I need to open the same parent after the end of new element. The the final line should be

```
<AnyTag>here is a <i>sample </i><span class="ClassB">test</span><i> text</i> and more text</AnyTag>
```

If I select the word "more" then

```
<AnyTag>here is a <i>sample test text</i> and <span class="ClassA">more</span> text</AnyTag>.
```

Appreciate any pointers in this regard.

Regards
Dominic

Comment: This is similar to `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111704/rangy-js-jquery-split-node` but with a range selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll need to split the text node containing 'sample test text' at two indexes so that you have three side by side text nodes: 'sample ', 'test', and ' text'. (Note the spaces in sample and text).

Second, create a range that encompasses the start of the parent node to the end of 'sample ' text node. Extract the contents.

```
var range, frag;
range = rangy.createRange();
range.setStartBefore(parent); //your 'i' tag
range.setEndBefore(textNode); //your text node 'sample '
frag = range.extractContents(); //extract a document fragment - removes items from dom
parent.parentNode.insertBefore(frag, parent); //place the fragment before the parent node
```

Repeat those same steps, this time creating a range from the start of the text node ' text' to the end of the parent.

```
var range, frag;
range = rangy.createRange();
range.setStartAfter(textNode); //your text node ' text'
range.setEndAfter(parent); //your 'i' tag
frag = range.extractContents(); //extract a document fragment - removes items from dom
parent.parentNode.insertBefore(frag, parent.nextSibling); //place the fragment after the parent node
```

Finally, the unwrap the contents of the original parent node 'i' and re-wrap it with your new tag.

If any of this isn't clear, let me know. I've been building a WYSIWYG editor and have tested this idea thoroughly.