# Split HTML Tags when applying custom styling

Tags: javascript, html, rangy

When you are using a WYSIWYG editor, and you select text and apply, for example, bold to it, the browser will wrap the selection with a `<span style="font-weight:bold">` tag (assuming you've called `document.execCommand("useCSS", false)` and/or `document.execCommand("styleWithCSS", true)`).  Now, if you select a subset of that and again apply bold, it will split the original bold tag into something like the following

```
<span style="font-weight:bold">Something</span>
Not selected 
<span style="font-weight:bold">Selected</span>
```

In a product I'm working on, we support a range of WYSIWYG features, including some that aren't directly supported by execCommand (like adding a level (class) of text to apply both font-family and font-size), and we are running into issues with nested tags.  Is there a way to tell the browser to remove the current range from the styling and essentially close previous tags and open new ones after the content?

I don't immediately see something in the [execCommand reference](http://help.dottoro.com/larpvnhw.php).

We are using [rangy 1.2.3](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) to some success, but I don't know if there's some command that I'm missing.

This gets more complicated as you add multiple styles, since adding bold and italic to the above example, then removing bold in the middle will produce three spans, two with bold and italic text, and the middle with just italic.

For the moment, we are restricting use of our editor to Chrome.

Comment: yes, forcing the user to use markup would be a more stable solution, but the people using the application arent familiar with that, so we have to offer a WYSIWYG editor for them to create their materials

Comment: I plan to write a module to do this in Rangy and did get reasonably far with it last year, but realistically it's unlikely to be ready for months.

Comment: Have you tried the `removeFormat` command? That's the only thing you have at your disposal in this case.

Comment: @skyline3000 that would work if we wanted to just, for example, unbold.  However, a more complicated example is taking a section of bolded, italic text and unbolding the middle portion.  This will produce a section of bold italic, a section of just italic, and a section of bold italic, in that order.  Unfortunately, remove format would remove everything.

Comment: I've been working with similar stuff for the past 6 months. I might be able to help you but I'm afraid, I really don't get what you mean to do

Comment: What is the difference between what you are asking to do and this [example](http://help.dottoro.com/external/examples/ljcvtcaw/execCommand_3.htm)?

Comment: we have a custom thing that is not supported by execCommand, one is adding a "class" of text (level1,level2, etc) to the selection.  Rangy does help alot there.  The other is increase/decrease font size that doesnt include `<small>` or `<big>` tags

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rangy (JS/jQuery) split node](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111704/rangy-js-jquery-split-node)

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is the messy output, which renders correctly, you should approach it from an editor-agnostic angle because this affects all HTML butespecially [rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/) and other WYSIWYG-editor/user-formatted code.

The quickest way to reduce the chaos is to limit the markup options available to the user:

- Restrict (if not disable) typefaces or other styles/elements with a lot of code
- Consider solutions designed precisely for this dilemma such as BBCode or Markdown syntax

If you can't swap the editor because the clients need the red/blue text from MS Word, [PHP Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/tidy.examples.basic.php) should be sufficient as it can handle even MS Office's HTML-export! The following function with `merge-spans` configured should do the trick.

```
function tidyHTML($input){
    $tidy = new tidy();
    $config = array(
        'ascii-chars' => true,
        'bare' => true,
        'clean' => true,
        'drop-empty-paras' => true,
        'drop-proprietary-attributes' => true,
        'hide-endtags' => true,
        'indent' => true,
        'logical-emphasis' => true,
        'merge-spans' => true,
        'show-body-only' => true,
        'word-2000' => true,
        'wrap' => false
    );
    return $tidy->repairString($input, $config);
}
echo tidyHTML($wysiwyg_output);
```

Documentation for the options can be found [here](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html).

Comment: This is not a particularly helpful answer.  This is directed at HTML/Javascript, not PHP.  In addition, this is not really about messy HTML that displays right, but more about avoiding scenarios where tags are nested in a way that results in invalid display, such as `<span class="level1">ABC <span class="level2"> DEF</span> GHI</span>` which should be `<span class="level1">ABC</span> <span class="level2">DEF</span> <span class="level1">GHI</span>`  This particular example *is* solved by rangy with the undoToSelection of level1 before applying level2, but more specific scenarios exist.

Comment: Further, it was stated in a comment above that BBCode and Markdown (or really any sort of markup syntax) arent applicable.

Comment: Sorry. I had a bit of trouble understanding exactly what you were asking and didn't see BBCode/Markdown mentioned above... Regardless, there's a question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/11111704/1105203) in the sidebar here that seems the same as yours with a linked solution: http://help.dottoro.com/external/examples/ljcvtcaw/execCommand_3.htm