# insert nested elements at caret position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, rangy

I am making use of a contenteditable div in combination with the rangy for inserting, deleting, changing ,commenting and formatting options in HTML at caret position .
 i have implemented inserting a new paragraph using rangy function SplitAtcaret : http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/rr9qs/2/. this is working good .

now i need to implement same inserting new section like a paragraph concept in sections .

sections for example :

Input HTML:

```
<div class="section_level1" >
    <h1>First Level section Heading</h1>
    <p>Level First some text some text some paragraphs. </p>
    <div class="section_level2" >
        <h1>Second Level section Heading</h1>
        <p>Second level some text <rangy position> insert new section (level 1)  here  </rangy posiiton > some text some paragraphs. </p>
        <div class="section_level3" >
            <h1>Third Level section Heading</h1>
            <p>Third level some text dummy text dummy text.some paragraphs. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Need Output Html as ( when inserting a new section at caret position ( inside second level     ). ):

```
<div class="section_level1" >
    <h1>First Level section Heading</h1>
    <p>Level First some text some text some paragraphs. </p>
    <div class="section_level2" >
        <h1>Second Level section Heading</h1>
        <p>Second level some text <p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section_level1" >  
    <h1>Level 1 heading goes here </h1>
    <p> Level 1 contents goes here. </p>
    <div class="section_level2" >
        <h1>dummy heading</h1>
        <p>Second level some text <p>
        <div class="section_level3" >
            <h1>Third Level section Heading</h1>
            <p>Third level some text dummy text dummy text.some paragraphs. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i want to know what are all open elements available before the caret position .can anyone please help .

Answer (score 1):

You could use Tim Down's [splitParaAtCaret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111704/rangy-js-jquery-split-node):

> ```
> function splitParaAtCaret() {
>     var sel = rangy.getSelection();
>     if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
>         // Create a copy of the selection range to work with
>         var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
>
>         // Get the containing paragraph
>         var p = range.commonAncestorContainer;
>         while (p && (p.nodeType != 1 || p.tagName != "P") ) {
>             p = p.parentNode;
>         }
>
>         if (p) {
>             // Place the end of the range after the paragraph
>             range.setEndAfter(p);
>
>             // Extract the contents of the paragraph after the caret into a fragment
>             var contentAfterRangeStart = range.extractContents();
>
>             // Collapse the range immediately after the paragraph
>             range.collapseAfter(p);
>
>             // Insert the content
>             range.insertNode(contentAfterRangeStart);
>
>             // Move the caret to the insertion point
>             range.collapseAfter(p);
>             sel.setSingleRange(range);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Modify the code that searched for the containing element to search for the class name:

```
    while (p && (p.nodeType != 1 || p.className != "section_level1") ) {
        p = p.parentNode;
    }
```